# appleTV: URLSession.shared.dataTask download empty

Tags: swift, nsurlsession, tvos

I try to load an image with newest version of XCode and AppleTV but suddenly the payload is always nil while the status code of the response is 200.  I also recognised SSL errors in my console. The download fails with images that are availabe in my browser. E.g. https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg

```
     private func fetchImage(url: URL) {
            dispatchGroup.enter()

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {(data, response, error) in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                    self.dispatchGroup.leave()
                    return
                }
                logger.error("Download failed \(response?.suggestedFilename ?? url.lastPathComponent)")
                //simplified here
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                self.dispatchGroup.leave()
                }.resume()
        }
```

Any idea what might cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems okay to me (Tested). The SSL error is happening because you need to set up App security in your Plist file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```